# Let $G$ be a group of order $6$. Let $a,b\in G$ with $|a|=3$ and $|b|=2.$ Prove that $⟨a⟩\cap ⟨b⟩ = \{e_G\}.$

Tags: group-theory

I already showed $\{e_G\} \subseteq \langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle,$ now I need to show $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle \subseteq \{e_G\}.$ Starting with some element in $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle$ and using Lagrangeʻs Theorem. But not sure how to put it together I know its simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to stack!

Take an element in the intersection $c$. Since $c\in \langle a \rangle$, using the Lagrange theorem the order of $c$ has to divide $3$. In the same way, since $c\in \langle b\rangle$, then the order of $c$ has to divide $2$.

Then the order of $c$ divides $2$ and $3$, so it is $1$. The unique element of $G$ that has order $1$ is $e_G$ so $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle \subseteq \{e_G\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and for a helpful answer!

Comment: @PhysicsBish It's a pleasure

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Lagrange's theorem, note that the order of the intersection must divide $2$, since it is contained in a cyclic group of order $2$, and it must also divide $3$. What positive integer divides both $2$ and $3$?

Comment: 1 which is the cardinality of the identity?

Comment: @PhysicsBish Every subgroup must contain the identity, so there's only one subgroup of order $1$.

Comment: right I agree and see what you are saying. Thanks!

Comment: @PhysicsBish No problem.